# Get td text with select

Tags: python, select, html-table, beautifulsoup

I am trying to obtain the odds of the link and I get an error. DO you know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/spain/laliga'
r = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

##print([a.text for a in soup.select('#tournamentTable tr[xeid] [href*=soccer]')])

print([b.text for b in soup.select('#tournamentTable td[xodd]')])
```

I am expecting to obtain 10 rows and 3 columns, one per each odd.
However, I have the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.py", line 14, in <module>
    print([b.text for b in soup.select('#tournamentTable td[xodd]')])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1376, in select
    return soupsieve.select(selector, self, namespaces, limit, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/soupsieve/__init__.py", line 114, in select
    return compile(select, namespaces, flags, **kwargs).select(tag, limit)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/soupsieve/__init__.py", line 63, in compile
    return cp._cached_css_compile(pattern, namespaces, custom, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 214, in _cached_css_compile
    CSSParser(pattern, custom=custom_selectors, flags=flags).process_selectors(),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 1113, in process_selectors
    return self.parse_selectors(self.selector_iter(self.pattern), index, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 946, in parse_selectors
    key, m = next(iselector)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 1100, in selector_iter
    raise SelectorSyntaxError(msg, self.pattern, index)
  File "<string>", line None
soupsieve.util.SelectorSyntaxError: Invalid character '\x1b' position 17
  line 1:
#tournamentTable td[xodd]
                 ^
...
```

Comment: done...........

Comment: it looks like you have wrong char between `#tournamentTable` and `td[xodd]`. It may look like space but it has code `\x1b`. You may try to delete this char and put space again.

Comment: I can run code without error - but page uses JavaScript to put data `td[xodd]` and `BS` can't run JavaScript so code can't get this data. You will need Selenium to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: how could I do this using selenium?

Comment: documentation for [Selenium-Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: I added code with Selenium in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have wrong char between `#tournamentTable` and `td[xodd]`. It may look like space but it has code `\x1b`. You may try to delete this char and put space again.

I can run your code without this error. But this page uses JavaScript to get data and `BS` can't run JavaScript. You may need Selenium to control web browser which can run JavaScript and you can get HTML with data.

Or you can use DevTool in Chrome/Firefox to check if JavaScript read data from some url and read data from the same url.

I found url

```
https://fb.oddsportal.com/ajax-sport-country-tournament/1/YLO7JZEA/X0/1/?_=1558215347943
```

Last part is current date as timestamp * 1000

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1558215347943/1000)) 

# 2019-05-18 23:35:47.943000

dt = datetime.datetime.now()
print(int(dt.timestamp()*1000))

# 1558216525573
```

Using `requests.Session()` and better `headers` I can read from this url. It gives data as JavaScript code but after cutting some part I get data in JSON format which can be converted to Python dictionary

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json

s = requests.Session()

headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'
}

url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/spain/laliga'
r = s.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(r.text.find('xodd'))
print([b.text for b in soup.select('#tournamentTable td[xodd]')])

headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0',
    'Referer': 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/spain/laliga/',
}

r = s.get('https://fb.oddsportal.com/ajax-sport-country-tournament/1/YLO7JZEA/X0/1/?_=1558215347943', headers=headers)
text = r.text[len("globals.jsonpCallback('/ajax-sport-country-tournament/1/YLO7JZEA/X0/1/', "):-2]

data = json.loads(text)
for key, val in data['d']['oddsData'].items():
    print('xeid:', key)
    print('xoid:', val['odds'][0]['oid'], 'avg:', val['odds'][0]['avg'])
    print('xoid:', val['odds'][0]['oid'], 'avg:', val['odds'][1]['avg'])
    print('xoid:', val['odds'][0]['oid'], 'avg:', val['odds'][2]['avg'])
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
xeid: ltB92yKu
xoid: 35vjqxv464x0x7qrck avg: 2.16
xoid: 35vjqxv464x0x7qrck avg: 3.5
xoid: 35vjqxv464x0x7qrck avg: 3.44
---
xeid: SW9D1eZo
xoid: 35vjrxv464x0x7qrcm avg: 1.33
xoid: 35vjrxv464x0x7qrcm avg: 5.71
xoid: 35vjrxv464x0x7qrcm avg: 8.83
---
xeid: Mg9H0Flh
xoid: 35vjsxv464x0x7qrco avg: 1.99
xoid: 35vjsxv464x0x7qrco avg: 3.79
xoid: 35vjsxv464x0x7qrco avg: 3.68
---
xeid: zcDLaZ3b
xoid: 35vjtxv464x0x7qrcq avg: 1.57
xoid: 35vjtxv464x0x7qrcq avg: 4.38
xoid: 35vjtxv464x0x7qrcq avg: 5.95
---
```

---

**EDIT:** using Selenium

```
import selenium.webdriver

url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/spain/laliga'

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#tournamentTable td[xodd]")

print([x.text for x in items])
```

Result:

```
['4.26', '4.07', '1.80', '1.99', '3.79', '3.68', '1.57', '4.38', '5.95', '2.13', '3.19', '3.94', '7.82', '5.00', '1.41', '2.16', '3.50', '3.44', '1.33', '5.71', '8.83', '2.58', '3.52', '2.73', '1.49', '5.31', '5.66', '4.03', '4.21', '1.82']
```

Comment: How did you find the https://fb.oddsportal.com/ajax-sport-country-tournament/1/YLO7JZEA/X0/1/?_=1558215347943 url in dev tools?? Thank you

Comment: I opened DevTool in Firefox, went to tab `Network`, loaded page and I saw all requests from browser to server. There is options to select only `XHR` (AJAX) and/or `JS`. I selected both and started checking responses for all requests - this url seemed more interesting so I checked if there is one of value from table - ie. `4.26`